# C # foreach repeats 300+ times

Tags: c#, foreach, datagridview

I have a program that loads a local HTML page with a table from which it will extract several results, which it will integrate into a DataGridView.

[Image of the program that returns the problem...]:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/43iNt.jpg

Here comes the problem, I am using foreach and it repeats the operation 300+ times ...

I do not understand, nor do I find where the problem is.
Could you enlighten me?
Thanks.

[HTML code from which I am trying to extract the data]:

```
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" style="border-width:0px;width:809pt;border-collapse:collapse;">
<tbody>
<tr style="height:16.4pt;">
<td class="sd2f9551a" style="width:42.9pt;height:16.4pt;"></td>
<td class="s054608a3" style="height:15.7pt;padding:2px 2px 2px 2px;width:70.8pt;">601</td>
<td class="s828d7148" style="height:15.7pt;padding:2px 2px 2px 2px;width:106.6pt;">001834820601</td>
<td class="s828d7148" colspan="7" style="height:15.7pt;padding:2px 2px 2px 2px;width:128.1pt;"></td>
<td class="s828d7148" colspan="3" style="height:15.7pt;padding:2px 2px 2px 2px;width:121pt;"></td>
<td class="sf7752056" colspan="6" style="height:15.7pt;padding:2px 2px 2px 2px;width:214pt;"></td>
<td class="s054608a3" style="height:15.7pt;padding:2px 2px 2px 2px;width:78pt;">EMBARCADO</td>
<td class="s9a0851f4" style="width:42.9pt;height:16.4pt;"></td>
</tr>
<tr style="height:15.7pt;">
<td class="sd2f9551a" style="width:42.9pt;height:15.7pt;"></td>
<td class="s054608a3" style="height:15pt;padding:2px 2px 2px 2px;width:70.8pt;">602</td>
<td class="s828d7148" style="height:15pt;padding:2px 2px 2px 2px;width:106.6pt;">001834820602</td>
<td class="s828d7148" colspan="7" style="height:15pt;padding:2px 2px 2px 2px;width:128.1pt;"></td>
<td class="s828d7148" colspan="3" style="height:15pt;padding:2px 2px 2px 2px;width:121pt;"></td>
<td class="sf7752056" colspan="6" style="height:15pt;padding:2px 2px 2px 2px;width:214pt;"></td>
<td class="s054608a3" style="height:15pt;padding:2px 2px 2px 2px;width:78pt;">EMBARCADO</td>
<td class="s9a0851f4" style="width:42.9pt;height:15.7pt;"></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

[Fragment of the code that returns the problem...]:

```
foreach (HtmlNode table in doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//tbody"))
            {
                foreach (HtmlNode row in table.SelectNodes("//tr[(@style='height:16.4pt;') or (@style='height:15.7pt;')]"))
                {
                    DataRow r = dt.NewRow();
                    int i = 0;

                    HtmlNodeCollection cells = row.SelectNodes("td");
                    if (cells == null)
                        continue;
                    foreach (HtmlNode cell in cells)
                    {
                        r[i] = cell.InnerText;
                        i++;
                    }
                    dt.Rows.Add(r);
                }
            }
```

Comment: did you run it in a debugger?  this code seems fine, could it be this code is called more than once?

Comment: This is a portion of the HTML code from where im parsing rows to datagridview (https://controlc.com/3ff5f881). There must be something in the HTML code that force the foreach to repeat 358 times. Im still invistigating.

Comment: ok -- you have over 350 tables in that example you sent -- thus I'd expect the outer table loop to run 350 times and the inter loops to run at least that many times --so the code is working as expected based on what it says to do.  What did you expect it to do?

Comment: I solved it, to prevent it to repeat 358 times i just replaced the first foreach from //tbody to //div[@id='MvcViewerReportPanel'], as it was repeating 358 times for each tbody found... Thanks.